# do we have more memory space for static variables?

Tags: c++, memory, static

```
int dp[2009][2009]

static int dp[2009][2009];
```

I made a c++ program in which i declared an arry as
     int dp[2000][2000] 
the program stopped working due to very much memory allocation .when i declared it as  static
     int dp[2009][2009] , the program worked fine .
whats the reason for this  ??

Comment: Is this at global scope or within a function?

Comment: its declared inside the main function

Answer (score 5):

Variables with automatic storage can only use a small, implementation-dependent amount of space ("the stack"). By contrast, variables with static storage duration can use a much larger amount of space, constrained mostly by the global machine constraints.

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism within the language to tell you how much space is available for automatic variables. It's an implementation-dependent limit that when you overstep it produces undefined behaviour, but you cannot know what the limit is or how much you have left...

Comment: He didn´t say anything about initialization

Comment: There are implementation-dependent ways to retrieve the size of the stack space and also to change it. (E.g., http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)

Comment: @ooga: Finding the total size, perhaps. Finding out how much you have left is even harder...

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point. I suppose you could get the address of argc (as an approximation of the top of the stack), then subtract from that the address of the latest pushed item (minus its size) and compare that to the limit. Not perfect, but gives an approximation.

Comment: okay ..the static variables and global variables are stored in the bss segment which is different from that of local variables

Comment: @user3696933: Well, that's at least true on one very specific platform with one very specific compiler... but yes.