# How big can a globally declared data structure be?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, global-variables, heap-memory

I have a global vector that I load data into, which is then read from later in my program.

If I have say, 1000000 elements pushed back into this vector, will it cause any problems such as those created by overflowing the stack? How much memory space is a available in the global scope?

Comment: Assuming you are using a local variable of type std::vector, it will not use stack memory, but heap memory. The total amount of memory used depends on your standard library implementation as well as the size of each element, and how each element manages its own memory. What data type are you putting in the vector?

Answer (score 1):

As per `C++11 section 23`, unless your type provides a specialised allocator, sequence containers such as `vector` will use `std::allocator`, which gets its memory using `new`. In other words, using dynamic memory allocation functions ("from the heap" in layman's parlance).

So, provided you follow the rules, there's no way to corrupt the stack using that container, as might be the case if you did something like:

```
void function(void) {
    int xyzzy[999999999];
    :
}
```

That's not to say you can't run out of memory, the heap isn't infinite in size, as shown in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {
    std::vector<const char*> *v = new std::vector<const char*>();
    long count = 0;
    while (1) {
        try {
            v->push_back("xyzzy");
            count++;
        } catch (std::exception &e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << count << " pushbacks done.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (on my system):

```
std::bad_alloc
134217728 pushbacks done.
```

But getting an exception because you're run out of memory is a far cry from corruption caused by stack overflow or running out of static storage duration ("global") space.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> If I have say, 1000000 elements pushed back into this vector, will it cause any problems such as those created by overflowing the stack?

No, it won't. When you create an `std::vector`, the memory for the data is allocated from the heap, not from the memory reserved for global data.

Question:

> How much memory space is a available in the global scope?

I don't have an answer to that. It might be irrelevant given the answer to the first question.

You might find [this answer to another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23996361/434551) relevant.